# Replace value in an array of struct c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following public struct in C#:

```
public struct Route
{
    public float Start; 
    public float End; 
    public float Range; 
    public bool InConstruction; 
};
```

I want to replace every property Range of Route used as an array of struct in an other class (Route[]). I did the following which works fine:

```
//dest.Route = new Route[]; 
for (var i = 0; i < dest.Route.Count; i++)
{
    dest.Route[i].Range = dest.Route[i].End - dest.Route[i].Start; 
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this loop or just other ways to implement this solution?

Maybe with desc.Route.Select(i => i.Range = i.End - i.Start); ?

Comment: Why not define `Range` as a computed property, like `public float Range => End - Start;`? That way you don't have to recompute it again.

Comment: That's just an example here. This struct is used multiple time in the project and it can't be change. And the solution I have works fine. It simply curiosity on how to implement this solution other ways.

Comment: @user14645785 Sounds like an XY problem. Can you tell us _why_ it cannot be changed? If you need the computation to be on-demand, you can add a method to the struct named something like `CalculateRange`. Then, you can do `foreach (var route in desc.Route) route.CalculateRange();`. Or if `desc.Route` is a list: `desc.Route.ForEach(r => r.CalculateRange());`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I thought their might be a way to implement this solution with `var temp = desc.Route.Select(i => i.Range = i.End - i.Start);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the struct, then no, you've done the most optimal thing. Even if you do find some solution with Linq, it's eventually just going to boil down to a loop like you have.

If you're dead set on using Linq, you'd need to do something like this:

```
desc.Route = desc.Route.Select(d => {
    d.Range = d.End - d.Start;
    return d;
})
.ToArray();
```

I'll let you be the judge if that's "better" for your project or not. This does go against some of the principles of Linq, mostly the "don't cause side effects".

This:

```
.Select(i => i.Range = i.End - i.Start)
```

Doesn't work (though it is legal syntax) because the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned, so you'd be selecting *just the float assigned to the Range property*, not the full Route object. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jSKZlj

---

If you can change the struct:

If `Range` is *always* the `End` field minus the `Start` field, then you could just compute it *when you need to read the value*, rather than preemptively. Shamelessly taking [Etienne de Martel's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016993/replace-value-in-an-array-of-struct-c-sharp#comment128962032_73016993):

```
public struct Route
{
    public float Start; 
    public float End; 
    public float Range => End - Start;
    public bool InConstruction; 
};
```

Now there's no need to do the loop calculation at all. The value for each object will be calculated as soon as you read the `Range` property.